# Count elements in defined groups in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe and I want to count how many times we have element e.g `[1,5,2]` in a/each column.

I could do something like

```py
elem_list = [1,5,2]

for e in elemt_list:
 (df["col1"]==e).sum()
```

but isn't there a better way like

```py
elem_list = [1,5,2]
df["col1"].count_elements(elem_list)

#1 5    # 1 occurs 5 times
#5 3    # 5 occurs 3 times
#2 0    # 2 occurs 0 times
```

Note it should count all the elements in the list, and return "0" if an element in the list is not in the column.

Comment: FYI, [what I initially suggested is the fastest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70757185/16343464), `value_counts` first, then `reindex`. The other methods have a cost of filtering or building the Categorical.

Comment: Thanks! Thats noted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,1,5,1,5,1,1,4,3]})

elem_list = [1,5,2]
df['col1'].value_counts().reindex(elem_list, fill_value=0)
```

output:

```
1    5
5    2
2    0
```

benchmark (100k values):

```
# setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.randint(0,10, size=100000)})

df['col1'].value_counts().reindex(elem_list, fill_value=0)
# 774 µs ± 10.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

pd.Categorical(df['col1'],elem_list).value_counts()
# 2.72 ms ± 125 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

df.loc[df["col1"].isin(elem_list), 'col1'].value_counts().reindex(elem_list, fill_value=0)
# 2.98 ms ± 152 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.randint(0,1000, size=100000)})` ?

Comment: @jezrael more or less the same values in the same order, 900µs to 2ms. I guess all solutions need to read all elements at least once. In my case this is directly done to count, then done.

Answer (score 2):

Pass to the `Categorical` which will return 0 for missing item

```
pd.Categorical(df['col1'],elem_list).value_counts()
Out[62]: 
1    3
5    0
2    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Note, I get an error using pandas 1.2.4 here!

Answer (score 0):

First filter by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and then use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), last if order is important add [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
df.loc[df["col1"].isin(elem_list), 'col1'].value_counts().reindex(elem_list, fill_values=0)
```

Comment: Will this also count the elements that are not present in the dateframe? (I.E. a missing value)

Comment: @sagi - no, it count only filtered values from list

Comment: OP also wanted these values to be present with count of 0..

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":np.random.randint(0,10, 100)})
df[df["col1"].isin([0,1])].value_counts()

# col1
# 1       17
# 0       10
# dtype: int64
```